# SQL table logic, which way is correct

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am having an argument with myself over the best way to do this.

Here is the scenario.

I have a table that has a list of users in it.

For simplicity let's say it looks like this:

```
Mike | male
Amy  | female
Andy | male
```

and so on.

I then have a list of colours, let's say 4 colours:

```
red
blue
green
yellow
```

any of the users can have one or more of the colours assigned to them.

**Do I** add a new column to the users table called `assignedColours`, create a new table called `colours` that looks like this:

```
id   |   colour
1    |   red
2    |   blue
3    |   green
4    |   yellow
```

and then assign then store an array in the users `assignedColours` coloumn like

```
Mike   | Male   | 2,3
Amy    | Female | 1,3,4
```

**Or**  do I create a colour table with columns of the colours and assign the users to that column like:

```
Red     |   Blue    |   Green    |   Yellow
        |   Mike    |   Mike     |   
Amy     |           |   Amy      |   Amy
```

or is there a better way of doing this all together?

I am looking for an answers as to which one is the preferred way and why.

Comment: Neither of the above: When a decision is finally reached.... did you win or lose?  Option 3) Create a table called userColors which contains the ID of the user and the colors.  This is an associative table and normally used when resolving a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: its was a draw as neither argument was the correct one. Now i have plenty of answers i can make peace with my self haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not creating an adjacency table? It will allow for easier joins and setting foreign keys.

Example:

***Users***

```
id| name | gender
-----------------
1 | Mike | male
2 | Amy  | female
3 | Andy | male
```

***Colors***

```
id | name
1  | red
2  | blue
3  | green
4  | yellow
```

***UserColors***

```
user_id | color_id
1       | 3
1       | 2
2       | 1
4       | 2
```

The `UserColors` table allows you to associate the `Users` with the `Colors`.
The concept is known as `adjacency table` or `join table` and is used to map `one2many` and `many2many` relations.

You can find a more developed example here: http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/

Comment: All great answers and pretty much the same thank you but i have to pick one, it wasn't easy :P

Answer (score 4):

Your first solution will give you problems if you need to search by colours.

Your second would give you extra work when adding more colours.

An additional table joining people & colours would be a good way to go. Check out information on Many-To-Many Relationships : http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

You would want a UserColours table...as well as users & colours.

2 colums, UserId, ColourId

Primary key on UserId, ColourId so they do not have duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the idea behing RDS (Relational Data Store) such as MySQL, is to have the [data normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and thus, easily searchable.

Because of that, your best bet, is to save a table of colors, a table of users and a many-to-many table, saving the users-colors, their definition would be something along this line

users table

```
id | int
name | varchar
gender | varchar
```

colors table

```
id | int
name | varchar
```

users_colors table

```
id | int
user_id | int
color_id | int
```

this way, you can easily find all users having a certain color, whereas with an un-normalized scheme, you would run into a problem, how would you query for users with a certain color and not another?